# Как добавить запись в базу данных через приложение на PyQt5

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt5, qtablewidget

База Данных PostgreSQL на Debian. Пишу приложение на Python - PyQt5 для взаимодействия с БД.
В таблице приложения всегда есть пустая строка. Нужно чтобы по нажатию кнопки считывались данные с этой строки (которые я вобью заранее) и добавились в базу данных. Делал через .format но данные не добавляются. В чем проблема?
'

```
def addRecord(self):
    rows = self.table.rowCount()-1
    fields = []
    for i in range(29):
        fields.append(self.table.itemAt(rows, i).text())
    
    query_ins = "INSERT INTO АБШ VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})".format(*fields)   
    print(query_ins)
    query = QSqlQuery(query_ins)`
```

Comment: а где собственно выполнение запроса? query.exec()

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите для чего вам БД. Как связана ваша БД и `table`? Что вы показываете в  `table`?